# FLUTTER CREATE : personalized HELLO WORLD app

Tags: flutter, dart

So every time I create a new project in flutter with `flutter create _my_app_name` the default flutter hello world app is generated automatically, and I have to change it from scratch.
**Am I able to change the default hello world app so that when I create a new project with `flutter create _my_app_name` it generates a personalized app**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll find the default app here :

```
{your-flutter-install}/packages/flutter-tools/templates/app/

/lib/main.dart.tmpl
```